# Analyze same network IOT device traffic

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I have simple home network:

```
DD-WRT router 192.168.0.1; Mask 255.255.255.0
Windows machine with Wireshark 192.168.0.106; Gateway  192.168.0.1
Espressif device that need to be analyzed 192.168.0.145; Gateway  192.168.0.1
```

I would like to know which MQTT server my Espressif device is trying to communicate with. Can I find it with Wireshark that runs on Windows machine? Currently I see only it's broadcast ARP packet. What are the ways of gathering required information? Should I somehow use DD-WRT router to get this info?

Comment: Is the code running on this "Espressif" device something you flashed to it? Do you have an MQTT server?

Comment: Code in "Espressife" is not mine. I need to know which server it calls